# Bottle - Django-style URLs and passing arguments

Tags: django, url, variables, routes, bottle

I have found this code which enables routes in Bottle to be stored in a similar way to Django:

```
from bottle import route

# Assuming your *_page view functions are defined above somewhere
urlpatterns = (
    # (path, func, name)
    ('/', home_page, 'home'),
    ('/about', about_page, 'about'),
    ('/contact', contact_page, 'contact'),
)

for path, func, name in urlpatterns:
    route(path, name=name)(func)
```

I'm trying to get the `name` passed to the page view functions. Having gone through the source code of Bottle I cannot see how `name` can be sent to the function or even why it is used if it cannot be sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name is used to reference other pages (e.g. for `app.get_url`). The name of the current request callback is available through `request['bottle.route'].name`. Besides, you can use the `route(..., callback=...)` argument to avoid the double-call of the decorator.

Comment: The callback assignment works for me, not sure why but before I tired this again I kept getting errors about having additional arguments that weren't expected. I appreciate name being used to reference other pages but is there any way of including extra arguments passed to the function when the view is called and can I use rule = 'POST' to filter the methods? If this is possible it would be great as I'm getting incredible performance from Bottle compared to other frameworks.

Comment: Is ``functools.partial()`` what you are looking for?

Comment: Indeed functools.partial() looks particularly useful, thanks.